# Why is the jquery empty function so complicated?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I looked at the `jQuery` source code for the `.empty()` function:

```
empty: function() {
        for ( var i = 0, elem; (elem = this[i]) != null; i++ ) {
            // Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks
            if ( elem.nodeType === 1 ) {
                jQuery.cleanData( elem.getElementsByTagName("*") );
            }

            // Remove any remaining nodes
            while ( elem.firstChild ) {
                elem.removeChild( elem.firstChild );
            }
        }​
```

Couldn't it be a lot simpler with just changing the `innerHTML` to an empty string:

```
empty: function() {
        for ( var i = 0, elem; (elem = this[i]) != null; i++ ) {
                elem.innerHTML = "";
        }​
```

The `empty` [docs](http://api.jquery.com/empty/):

> Description: Remove all child nodes of the set of matched elements from the DOM.

Comment: It's explained by this comment in the code: `// Remove element nodes and prevent memory leaks`...

Comment: @nnnnnn. Yes, I'm actually asking how can it cause a memory leaks...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just think about `.data()` expandos and event handlers...  By just removing the DOM, you would create memory leaks every time.

Comment: Also, when combined with jQuery UI, it calls all of the cleanup methods defined in the destroy methods of widgets defined using the $.widget framework before the elements get removed.

Comment: +1 for correctly explaining about memory leaks.. I learned it hard way

Comment: @gdoron in javascript expando means, attaching additional properties to an object.

Comment: @gdoron: jQuery offers the `.data()` method which alles to store any kind of data on a specific Node. That data isn't stored directly on the Node but in a special container where it is linked to it. Those data would never get removed along with any event handler function or other data that is somewhere stored.

Comment: @jAndy In other words, in pure javascript only that problem would not exist because the data is a feature of jQuery?

Comment: @Armatus: interesting question and maybe a good standalone SO question. I have to admit that I'm not 100% aware right now how the differen garbage collectors work on native `addEventListener` calls and where/how those handler objects are stored.