# How to clear if there is no result

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a map. Whenever I click to state it pulls up the distributors and shows up.
However, if there is no result from the database it leaves the previous one on the page. 
What I want is if there is no result for that particular state I would like it to make container empty. How can I do it?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#SC").click(function() {
        if ($("div.SC_info").is(":hidden")) {
            $("#repinfo_container div.info_cont").removeClass("active");
            $("#repinfo_container div.info_cont").addClass("inactive");
            $("div.SC_info").slideDown("fast");
            $("div.SC_info").removeClass("inactive");
            $("div.SC_info").addClass("active");
            $("div.inactive").slideUp("fast");
        } else {}
    });
});​
```

Some more details 
Look to this picture. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cax38.png This is an interactive distribution map. The problem is for example in the database I have results(distributors) for CA(California). When I click it pulls up and shows at the bottom. However, if I click LA(state) since there is no result it shows the previous clicked state's results. What I want is if I don't have any results for this    state I want it to show that container instead of showing the previous result. I hope now it makes more sense.

Here is the source code of the whole page

pastebin.com/mxyDpZCx

Comment: What do you mean with "empty"? Maybe not setting `innerHTML = ''`...

Comment: @MaxArt. Your way can lead to a memory leak! [read this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10305479/601179)

Comment: @gdoron I know, it was just like killing a mosquito with a sledgehammer :) By the way, I think more modern browsers deal with memory leaks induced by `innerHTML` correctly or at least way better than in the past.

Comment: @MaxArt. It has nothing to do with modern browsers. jQuery holds data in the cache, and it's need to be told to remove them. I liked the sledgehammer  joke :)

Comment: @gdoron Ahh that's what you meant... Ok, I wasn't thinking about jQuery at all when I wrote the comment lol

Answer (score 1):

> What I want is if there is no result for that particular state I would like it to make container empty.

```
$("#repinfo_container").empty();
```

Comment: Where should I put this? The thing is I'm pulling data from database. My problem is if there is no result from database I would like to remove the previous one. Because else if keeps the previous one at the bottom.

Comment: @SNaRe. I didn't understand the question at all. :(

Comment: Look to this picture. http://i.imgur.com/vozKp.png This is an interactive distribution map. The problem is for example in the database I have results(distributors) for CA(California). When I click it pulls up and shows at the bottom. However, if I click LA(state) since there is no result it shows the previous clicked state's results. What I want is if I don't have any results for this    state I want it to show that container instead of showing the previous result. I hope now it makes more sense.

Answer (score 1):

you can do:

```
$(selector).html('');
```

A tip:

you should cache your selections to have better performance, like, instead of this:

```
$("div.SC_info").slideDown("fast");
$("div.SC_info").removeClass("inactive");       
$("div.SC_info").addClass("active");
```

you can have this:

```
var selection = $("div.SC_info");
selection.slideDown("fast");
selection.removeClass("inactive");       
selection.addClass("active");
```

That way you select the elements once and operate on selection, instead of selecting them three times.

Comment: Where should I put this? The thing is I'm pulling data from database. My problem is if there is no result from database I would like to remove the previous one. Because else if keeps the previous one at the bottom.

Comment: you put this in a callback function where you get your results from the database. just check for the response and if it's empty clear the container.

Comment: Isn't it possible to do it just with jquery ? http://pastebin.com/mxyDpZCx here is the full code of the page