# If .off automatically called when .remove is called?

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQuery:

```
var a = $("<a href='#'>Click me</a>")
var d = $("div:first");
a.appendTo(d);
a.on("click",function(){
   if(prompt('enter password') === 'password'){
      $(d).remove();
   }
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bujRr/

---

Question: Although the `<a>` doesn't exist anymore, the `click` was still bound to it.

1. Was the event binding removed? when the `<div>` was `.remove()`ed?
2. If it wasn't, could this cause performance problems after a theoretical few hundred runs?
3. Should I just call `.off()` before `.remove()`?

---

Note: No, I am not really storing any passwords in JS. I removed ajax calls as well as other code for the sake of having a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is the jquery empty function so complicated?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10305479/why-is-the-jquery-empty-function-so-complicated)

Comment: The answer is, all the events are removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well according to the documentation events are removed as well: http://api.jquery.com/remove/

> Similar to .empty(), the .remove() method takes elements out of the
>   DOM. Use .remove() when you want to remove the element itself, as well
>   as everything inside it. **In addition to the elements themselves, all
>   bound events and jQuery data associated with the elements are removed.
>   To remove the elements without removing data and events, use .detach()
>   instead.**

Answer (score 2):

> Was the event binding removed? when the `<div>` was `.remove()`ed?

Yes, events bound to a removed item (or its children) are automatically removed for you.

> If it wasn't, could this cause performance problems after a theoretical few hundred runs?

It would, but for the reason above it's not an issue

> Should I just call `.off()` before `.remove()`?

No.